# elasticsearch/graylog finding uuid string

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, graylog2

I'm using graylog(v2) and elasticsearch(v2.4) to store logs in a centralised manner, each log row is a string in the `message` field.

I can't figure out how to find en entry in the format:

```
{message: "[...] token:5.11348BFB-42A4-4CF0-BEB4-048162AF613B [...]"}
```

(Replace [...] with arbitrary text)

searching for `*048162*` gives me the result but searching for `*048162A*`, `*BEB*` or `*token:5.11348BFB-42A4-4CF0-BEB4-048162AF613B*` gives me no results found

It doesn't have to be via graylog, if it's somehow easier to do these kind of queries in kibana I can put the logs into elasticsearch directly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be possible by searching: `message: "token:5.11348BFB-42A4-4CF0-BEB4-048162AF613B"`